# File Transfer fails in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using the following code to transfer a PDF file to my app:

```
downloadAndOpenPdf() {
    this.tid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tid');

    const downloadUrl = jDrupal.user.yearTerm.booklet;

    //const path = this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;
    //const path = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/pdfs';
    const path = this.file.applicationStorageDirectory;

    const transfer = this.ft.create();

    transfer.download(downloadUrl, path + 'term-' + this.tid + '.pdf').then(entry => {
      const url = entry.toURL();

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
      } else {
        this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      }
    });
  }
```

I can see that transfer is a FileTransfer object (good); but on the transfer.download() call i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FileTransferError: {"code":null,"source":null,"target":null,"http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":null}
```

I have tried various storage paths as can be seen in code and all give valid paths; but none work (assuming the issue is the path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I hadn't installed all the libs that were required and then wasn't using the correct storage location. This post cleared everything up:

https://ovpv.me/open-pdf-ionic-4/

Answer (score 0):

```
  downloadViaURL(video){
    let url = "https://download.com/file.whatever";
    let path = this.file.externalDataDirectory + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    this.file.checkFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)).then(value => {
      console.log('Is already downloaded');
    },reason => {

      console.log('reason : ',JSON.stringify(reason))
      this.fileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();

      this.fileTransferObject.download(url,path,true).then(value => {
        console.log('download : ',JSON.stringify(value));

      },rejected=>{
        console.log('download rejected : ',JSON.stringify(rejected));

        this.file.removeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory,url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)).then(value => {
          console.log('removeFile : ',JSON.stringify(value))
        },reason =>{
          console.log('removeFile reason : ',JSON.stringify(reason))

        }).catch(error=>{
          console.log('removeFile error : ',JSON.stringify(error))
        })


      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('download error : ',JSON.stringify(err));
      })


      this.fileTransferObject.onProgress(value=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value.loaded/value.total *100))
        this.ngZone.run(()=>{
          this.downloadProgress = (value.loaded/value.total *100).toFixed(0) + '%';
        })
      })

    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log('error : ',JSON.stringify(error))
    })

  }
```